# unable to delete VPC in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I've got a problem here. I want to delete VPC in AWS but I got these errors. Anyone know what to do?
[image]

[image]

All help appriciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically VPC has too many components like Subnet, internet gateway, NAT gateway, EIP, instances etc... When you try to delete the VPC it will try to delete all dependent components inside the VPC by itself. If AWS can't delete any active components you will get the error.

Here, the error clearly mentions there is an active ENI attached. Click on the ENI link and check which instance the ENI is attached to. Terminate the instance if it's not required and try to delete the VPC again.